# How to merge .wav F32 audio file into rendered video file without loosing quality?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio

I edited and madup an F32 .wav in audacity. I want to merge it with the blender video file I rendered out without losing audio/video quality. How do I do this? Doesn't necessarily have to be done again via blender. If you suggest via blender please be specific on the settings, cause I've had many many problems with the audio rendering of blender.

Edit: without re-encoding I guess is what I'm asking? Just want the file in audacity to sound the exact same as the file paired with the video.

Comment: Blender will re-compress the video and video, adding more artifacts. If you already have the video file then you only want to "mux" the two streams together. There are several programs available to do that one task. You can use ffmpeg by specifying "copy" as the codec, something like  `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -acodec copy -vcodec copy mixed.mp4`

Comment: Several programs....such as? I mean you can look online but I can't necessarily find information about whether they do the same thing blender does or not....or if they respect the format or if they re-encode and drag the quality down someplace. I gotta mix like 23gb video file with 1gb audio file, what kinda information would I look for when searching to get what I want? I mean VLC player has the ability to combine audio and video, I read online briefly it can hurt quality tho (idk if true or not). Shouldnt blender work if I'm mixing with lossless settings selected like: PCM+losslessH.264avi?

Comment: Blender will essentially "play back" the video, so it draws a frame to ram and then encodes it, even if you don't lose any quality with lossless codecs, you get the overhead that makes it a lot slower. I have only used ffmpeg for de/muxing so can't recommend others, I've just noticed muxing specific apps when looking for other info. I would expect an app that describes itself as muxing video/audio will not re-encode the video.

Comment: the video isn't mp4. the audio isn't mp3 the audio isn't aac either. its .wav. So how is that ffmpeg command gonna work? I can't find info on ffmpeg and on whether it allows you to combine formats like the ones I have. All I see are commands on how to combine aac with mp4 video.

Comment: All I see are commands on how to combine aac with mp4 video. everything I find assumes you are combining an mp4 video with some audio. I have a H.264 format, not mp4.

Comment: ffmpeg -i original.mkv -i audio.wav -c copy output.mkv  combined but the audio was completely screwed, like it switched to mono and went through something horrible.